What impacts would a north-south continent-spanning cliff (~1.5 km in height on average) have on climate and weather patterns (local and global)?
So, I've done a bunch of research on geography and weather, but searching for the effects of two particular features is proving difficult. I've found plenty of information on cliff erosion, but nothing about how a large cliff (or similar massive structure) might impact weather patterns and climate.
The main point of interest is the large cliff running down the middle of two large continents.
Relevant (?) facts:

It runs through the centre of the continents, north-south.
Combined, the continents are roughly the size of the Americas.
The planet is about halfway between Earth and Mars in size.
The cliff curves like a low-amplitude sine wave.
It faces east and averages 1-2 km high.
It was created suddenly by a cataclysmic event, not formed over time
(~100 years prior).
The trade winds blow eastward.
The planet has no tilt, wobble, and its orbit is a perfect circle (it was intentionally created that way), so it doesn't have "Earth-like" seasons. It has wet/dry seasons rather than hot/cold.
The sun rises in the west. Day and night are each exactly 12 hours at the equator.
There are two moons and a ring from a broken moon.

My current understanding is that due to convection and such (sunlight heating up the cliff, heating up the air, causing it to rise and meet the cooler air at the top of the cliff), weather along the cliff itself would be pretty chaotic and intense, since the temperature variation between the top and the bottom of the cliff is so extreme. But I don't know if that is correct, or what other effects the cliff might have.
A smaller scale but very related question. There is a city that is built at the base of a massive, slightly concave disc, which is half-buried in the ground. The disc is ~20 km in diameter, and only about 9 km of it is still above the surface - but that's still a ~9 km tall, ~18 km wide wall (it used to be the base of a flying city). The current city is built on the western side of this disc, on the concave side, in a relatively temperate area.
I don't know if the full-detail map was necessary but I thought it might be helpful.


You forgot the smaller scale but very related question. But don't add it. We answer only 1 question per post.

Hello @BinaryCat, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. For future reference, please know that very broad questions that could conceivably be answered by writing a book are prohibited. See the Book Rule in the [help/dont-ask]. Climate questions are among the most difficult to answer even when very specific consequences in very localized conditions are asked for. Asking for global consequences frequently results in a closed question. Please carefully read the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask] for more information.

As a note with no axial tilt the day length will be identical worldwide.

The atmospheric circulation that form what we call the 'trade winds' can form in both hemispheres... and they would be opposite of one another. As you flipped the direction of the sunrise/sunset, you should also flip the direction of the trade winds in BOTH hemispheres.

Look into the weather/climate effects of the 1-2km high cliff escarpment in the Venezuela plateau that Angel Falls occurs in. It's not continent spanning but will definitely give you some ideas

Lets review:

Rotation speed is Earthlike so you'll have a similar four cell Hadley Circulation.
The rotation direction is retrograde compared to Earth, so the Coriolis effect is going to be "backwards", this means that weather systems are going to travel east-to-west around the globe.

Your cliff is very tall and in the way of the prevailing wind systems of the globe; usually this would mean massive rainfall but in this case there is a mountain range between the cliffs and the prevailing wind along most of the distance so orographic rainfall along the cliff is largely going to be pretty muted. Most of the plain between the mountains and the cliff is going to be semi-arid or drier as it exists in a rain shadow, it could be as bad as a lowland version of the Atacama Desert especially in the northern basin. The air will still be pretty dry by the time it reaches the cliff and increasingly warm.
If the cliff is made of a dark material that soaks up considerable amounts of heat then a sustained west-east monsoon wind may flow from the western ocean towards the desert. If that is the case then where the two wind systems meet (more or less the line of the cliff) there will be considerable atmospheric instability, similar to tornado alley but on a transcontinental scale without any seasonality, just constant supercell thunderstorms etc...
All in all living anywhere near the cliff is going to be hard, bone dry where there isn't horizontal rain with the wind tearing your house apart. That middle sea is going to be pretty storm wracked as well, shallow, closed, and close to the equator hurricanes are probably a given, and again that's at any time of year because there are no seasons.
There is probably good potential for irrigated farming in the desert near the base of the cliff, rainwater captured along the storm line and transported by surface canal, or Qanat, into the lowlands.
